Mocking functions with multiple template arguments
I am trying to mock std::make_shared
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
class MakeSharedMock {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(std::shared_ptr<T>, MakeShared, (Args... args), (const noexcept));
};

int main(){
    MakeSharedMock<std::string> mock_make_shared;
}

However getting error like this
error: static assertion failed: This method does not take 1 arguments.
Parenthesize all types with unproctected commas.   
MOCK_METHOD(std::shared_ptr<T>, MakeShared, (Args... args), (const
noexcept));

If I omit first typename T, it compiles
template <typename... Args>
class MakeSharedMock {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(std::shared_ptr<int>, MakeShared, (Args... args), (const noexcept));
};

I wonder whether its possible to mock functions with multiple template arguments.

I am trying to reproduce it here but not sure what is missing https://godbolt.org/z/nEbM4bW77. Please provide a [mcve]

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: You have to instantiate the template: Demo

"If I omit first typename T, it compiles", In fact not, Demo. issues happens as soon sizeof...(Args) != 1.

I am trying to mock std::make_shared What? This looks very suspicious. Sound like question suffers from  XY problem. Why do you need to mock this at all? Definitely you are trying solve some problem in wrong way and you ask to make "the wrong way" to work.

I'm guessing you should use some factory pattern first then mock the factory.

@MarekR: Mocking some factories might be fine (and with minimal reproducible example, that becomes make_shared...).

@Marek R, In my environment, I have a function equivalent to std::make_shared which returns ara::core::Result https://github.com/okba-zoueghi/ara-core/blob/master/result.h. I want to test the case where make_shared fails, so trying to mock and return error with EXPECT_CALL.

@FaisalM What is exactingly your dependency. It looks like this dependency API returns Result which can contain value or error information (equivalent of std::expected from C++23).

GMock seems to not support variadic template, but you might use specialization as workaround:
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class MakeSharedMock;

template <typename T>
class MakeSharedMock<T>
{
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(std::shared_ptr<T>, MakeShared, (), (const noexcept));
};

template <typename T, typename T1>
class MakeSharedMock<T, T1>
{
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(std::shared_ptr<T>, MakeShared, (T1), (const noexcept));
};

template <typename T, typename T1, typename T2>
class MakeSharedMock<T, T1, T2>
{
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(std::shared_ptr<T>, MakeShared, (T1, T2), (const noexcept));
};

// ...

Demo
